# Partial match on a dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary, nlp, gate

I am working with GATE (Java Based NLP Framework) and want to find words with partial match with a dictionary. 
For example I have a disease dictionary with following terms

```
Congestive cardiac failure
Congestive Heart Failure
Colon Cancer
      .
      . 
      .
Thousands of more terms
```

Let's assume I have as string `"Father had cardiac failure last year"` from this string I want to identify "cardiac failure" as partial match because it occurs as part of a term in the dictionary.

I have seen some discussion on similar subject in Python, JS and C# but I am not sure what can help in such a case here. 
I wonder if I can utilize Aho-Corrasick over here.

Comment: @eowl hey thanks, i just committed to the proposal, but as of now I can not post my question over there, correct?

Comment: @eowl I used the same login as SO and thus it shows me the same name but not the same score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UIMA Concept Mapper annotator addon](http://uima.apache.org/downloads/sandbox/ConceptMapperAnnotatorUserGuide/ConceptMapperAnnotatorUserGuide.html) includes a functionality similar to what you are looking. You may consider:

- including using UIMA inside GATE: [http://gate.ac.uk/userguide/chap:uima](http://gate.ac.uk/userguide/chap%3auima)
- develop a similar component using the main ideas from the addon

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html). Treat each line of the dictionary as a document, and each sentence in the text as a query.

Comment: I thought of that, but I am sure that this technique will need a lot of iterations and match quality will not be great. As of now I am already using Lucene with the same dictionary for free text search and I get vivid results when I make a query like "knee pain"

Answer (score 1):

One question that arises is which substrings you want to include in the search. If you included all substrings just "Heart" would also be a match, but that is not really a disease. 
Maybe all right-aligned (word-)substrings (perhaps with length > 1) would be acceptable.

So one thing you could do is to train the Aho-Corrasick pattern matcher with the substrings you want to include. To keep the information from which dictionary term the substring came you probably need to modify the algorithm a bit (if keeping that information is important) or build another datastructure to look it up afterwards.

In any case I would convert the disease list and the documents you want to search to lower case before training/matching. If there is a chance of misspellings - there are also papers on fuzzy aho-corasick automata.